# How to delete a specific plug-in in GIMP

Tags: 20.04, gimp

How can I remove a plug-in from GIMP, keeping all other plug-ins intact? I use Ubuntu 20.04 and GIMP 2.10.18.

Comment: Gimp has its own support forum. https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Uninstall-plugins

Comment: @David Should I delete this question? I posted this since I saw my roommate posted another question about GIMP yesterday, regarding how to install plugins. Is Gimp Out of Scope for Askubuntu?

Comment: No it can be there for others that may not know that gimp has a forum.

Comment: I think this question is in-scope for AskUbuntu. Kalyani, I'm sure you are asking about removing a plugin from GIMP installed on a supported version of Ubuntu. You should add your Ubuntu version to the question, or as a tag, to make it clear. GIMP may be packaged differently for Ubuntu than other OSs, so removing a GIMP plugin on Ubuntu could be different than removing a plugin on a different OS.

Comment: @PJSingh I am sorry for the late reply, due to unforeseen circumstances. I have updated as you said. Is any further information needed?